# "AJAX" Calendar Widget that include Time Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, widget

Are there any existing AJAX/Javascript Date picker widgets/libraries that also allow you to select a time range?  That is,  after picking a date, an existing UI pops-up/becomes available to select a time range for the same.

I'm looking for example of things like [this](http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html).  UI Libraries that offer some form of date picking, followed by a step to pick a time range.

Yes, I know, a dozen different ways this could be implemented myself. I'm interesting in knowing what kind of preexisting libraries exist for this problem domain.

Comment: AJAX has become a generic term for "Javascript UI that interacts with the server".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some of the MANY choices:

- [Fancy Time Picker](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/GUI-Components/FancyTimePicker.htm)
- [NoGray Time Picker](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/GUI-Components/FancyTimePicker.htm)
- [This JQuery Plugin](http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/)
- [Any+Time](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/)
- [Another JQuery Plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/timepicker/)
- [JQuery pt.TimeSelect](http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html)
- [Clock Pick](http://www.jnathanson.com/index.cfm?page=jquery/clockpick/ClockPick)
- [Clock Picker](http://www.pit-r.de/timepicker/demo/pickerDemo.htm)
- [TimePickr](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/)
  -

John Resig (The J IN JQuery) has [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/picking-time/) to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to combine a DATE Plugin with a Time Plugin, don't try to cram both into one dialog